# Choose an image from android app and save it in MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, file-upload

I am a beginner in Android Studio. I need choose an image from android device and upload it to the server and save that in a MySQL table.
I wrote a simple PHP file and check that by POSTMAN and work correctly! in android side I wrote this codes:

```
    public class RequestHandler {

    public String sendGetRequest(String uri) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String result;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while((result = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(result);
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(25000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(25000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                response = br.readLine();
            } else {
                response = "Error Registering";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

and this codes for Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://excample.com/test.php";
public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";
public static final String TAG = "MY MESSAGE";
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
private Button btnChooseAndUpload;
private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnChooseAndUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseAndUpload);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    btnChooseAndUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnChooseAndUpload) {
        //Step1: Show File Chooser:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

        //Step2: Upload Image:
        UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
        ui.execute(bitmap);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}


class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog loading;
    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...", true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        loading.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
        String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

        String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, data);

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

when I run program every thing look correct but I don't received any data in table!

The PHP code in server is:

```
<?php


 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 $image = $_POST['image'];

 require_once('config.php');
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect');


 $sql = "INSERT INTO my_images (image) VALUES (?)";

 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

 $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

 if($check == 1){
 echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
 }else{
 echo "Error Uploading Image";
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
 echo "Error";
 }

?>
```

please help me to understand and fix this problem! thank you....

Comment: Convert your image to byte[] stream, then you can save it in SQLite, Realm or Server. Search, you will find many answers online; if not tell me I'll post answer.

Comment: Or you try to save image path

Comment: @janki yup can do that too, but I think converting to byte[] stream will give you the power to compress image as well as change extension of the image too; which I personally think is better. :)

Comment: `but I don't received any data in table!`. You should start telling which echo() you receive in your Android app.

Comment: Have you ever seen/used php statements like `if ( isset($_POST['image']) echo("image is set");` else .... NOT set! Well add them! Make your script robust.